# Using Decimal type increase the time-cost in power computation

Tags: python, optimization, decimal

As I am dealing with very small numbers, i changed the operation **(1) to (2)**.

After this transformation, the time-cost is the same but when I try to improve precision using decimal.Decimal and transforming **(2) to (3)** the time-cost explodes (~ 10 times ).

Is there a solution to solution to decrease the time and keep the same precision?

**(1)**

```
alpha = 1. (fyt *  qyt ) / (fxt * qxt)
```

**(2)**

```
pow(10, log10(fyt) + log10(qyt) - log10(fxt) - log10(qxt))
```

**(3)**

```
alpha = 10**(Decimal(fyt).log10() + Decimal(qyt).log10() - Decimal(fxt).log10() - Decimal(qxt).log10())
```

Comment: I'm curious: Why did you switch from (1) to (2)? Looks just slower and less precise to me. Do you have example numbers where (2) is better than (1)?

Comment: `a = 1e-300`
`b=1e-300`
`c = 1e-200`
`d = 1e-100`
`1. * (a*b) / (c *d) = 0` however
`pow(10,log10(a)  + log10(b) - log10(c) - log10(d)) = 1e-300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is to be expected since you have a power computation of the kind `10**x` here, which in the case of decimal should mean checking for precision after every step.

Consider the example below, where it is clearly visible that the decimal power operation is very costly:

```
In [6]: from decimal import Decimal

In [7]: %timeit 10**.0123456789
100000000 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ns per loop

In [8]: %timeit 10**Decimal(.0123456789)
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.3 µs per loop
```

---

So, Rather than doing a decimal operation on the (3) equation, do it on the first (1) directly:

```
alpha = (Decimal(fyt) *  Decimal(qyt)) / (Decimal(fxt) * Decimal(qxt))
```

This should work fast enough because there are only 3 operations happening in total, and should have the same precision as well because we are using `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an external package called `cDecimal`, which is a C implementation of the Decimal module. I've never used it but might want to try it out.